# car mobile charger blown my radio/ stereo

Tags: electrical, car, fuse, charger

When I used a Samsung car charger in the cigarette lighter, the power to the stereo (radio) went off. Before that, every thing was OK. So, what went wrong?

Suzuki Alto (Japanese)

If a fuse is blown, how can I get to the faulty fuse?

USB Charger [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyZxH.jpg)

[image]

Fuses under dashboard [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGURi.jpg)

[image]

Fuses description [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuH4f.jpg)

[image]

Fuses under bonnet [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOUbW.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2nd picture (fuses under dashboard) is where the radio fuse is located. If you look at your picture, you can see the fuses in the top left (those little plastic things with numbers on them).

The blue label in your picture says the radio fuse is the 5th one from the end in the middle row and has the number 15 on it. Most cars have a little plastic tool near the fuses to help you pull them out, if not, you may be able to use your fingers, or some thin pliers, or even a flat screwdriver. Just pull the fuse straight out and look at it. Compare it to this picture.
[image]

If the fuse is blown, replace it by a fuse with the same number on it (15 in the case of your radio). Some cars have spare fuses, if not they are inexpensive to buy at a parts store. When you are putting fuses back in, just push them all the way in with your finger. Press a little bit hard.